# How to troubleshoot ping request time out

Tags: wireless-networking, ping

I have a Windows 7 and an XP machine connected to a NETGEAR wireless router. Both machines can log into the network and surf the web. Both are connecting wirelessly.

I can ping the router from each machine and get a reply.
I can ping each machine from the router and get a reply.
But i cannot ping each machine from the other; getting a request time out.

Subnet IP Addresses are 192.168.1.* 
Router =1;
Win7 = 10;
XP = 11;

Firewall is currently off in both systems. Since i can ping from router im picking that not the problem anyway.

If i try to ping from xp to win7 i get Request Timed Out.
If i try to ping from Win7 to Xp i get destination host unreachable.

What should i do now? Thanks

Comment: if you run ipconfig /all from both workstations does the output make sense?

Comment: Yes. The gateway for both machines are pointing at the router and all the values look right. Each machine can also ping itself. thnx

Comment: What about ARP tables? You can try disable/enable the connections and/or repairing the connections on both systems.

Comment: Ok ive deleted all ARP entries and done an ipconfig /renew but still no response between systems.

Comment: Ive gone into the router and displayed the routing table. Althought the router IP address is in there the IP address foreach machine is not. I dont understand routing tables but shouldn;t the IP address of each machine be in the routers routing table?

Comment: @user28317 no ... If they really are on the same subnet, they don't go to Layer3 to communicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

k. Ive sorted the problem.

When i used some cat 5 on the XP machine i was able to ping it, but still couldn't ping to the Win7 machine. When i cat 5 the Win7 machine i could then ping that.

It was a router based setting. Wireless Isolation was enabled.

I saw it earlier but thought it meant something else but it actually means isolate the individual machines ***within the subnet*** from each other so you cant even ping machines on the same subnet. Seems an odd default but is kinda cool. ;)

Not sure if i should delete the post or not?

Comment: That's a great default if you're running the router in a coffee shop or something!

Comment: Yep. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also want to check other wireless settings on the router.  For example, a D-Link router also has "WMM Enable" and "Short GI", which are intended to make the network more reliable or faster but actually caused a similar issue (and you won't know until you experiment.)